# c++ ifstream only reading in one string need both read in

Tags: c++, string, fstream, ifstream

I have small amount of data in a file that looks like

New Mexico
50.9  10

this repeats with every state and whenever i hit states with two words for their title my program says pretty much says ooops we'll put first word in your string but the second one has no storage for it. With that it discontinues taking the rest of the data once that double worded title is encountered. Is there a way to take both words and put them in one string when reading my file in?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct AccountsDataBase{

    string stateName;
    double miles;
    int rests;

};

#define MAX 80

AccountsDataBase * account = new AccountsDataBase[MAX];


int readIn(ifstream& file){
    int count=0;    

    file >> account[count].stateName;
    file >> account[count].miles;
    file >> account[count].rests;


while( !file.eof() && count<MAX){

    count++;
    file >> account[count].stateName;
    file >> account[count].miles;
    file >> account[count].rests;




}    

    return count;
}




int main(){

   ifstream file;
   file.open("input.txt"); //opens data account records text

   if ( !file.fail() ) {
       int cnt = readIn(file);


       delete[] account;
   }


return 0;

}
```

Comment: Sorry to hear that. But, where's your code?

Comment: Also, are you trying to read just _only_ the states into one string for each line?

Comment: It's probably a bad thing trying to 2nd guess this type of question (no code, no clear description, e.g. what does "pretty much oops" mean in terms of program output), but I think, what he does, is to ''instream >> stringvar >> floatvar >> intvar'', which ends in trying to read "Mexico" in floatvar. From then on, everything is lost. What he needs to do, is to read one line into a string, split and take out the last two tokens, take the rest for the state name. Or write a proper parser. I promise to try to be more concise if we get seom code and properly quoted output :-)

Comment: @M.E.L. are you saying i should use the C token function to break this all up cause i was thinking about doing so since it adds a delimiter to the end of each token maybe i could then tell it to continue reading the  state name in until delimiter is reached and i will add code my apologies.

Comment: Hint: `>>` will stop parsing at white spaces.

Comment: @herohuyongtao how can i continue the parsing of the two words for the states name and store them in the same string in my structure

Comment: OP: I tried to answer your question prior to you updating it with relevant code. However, examining them in tandem with your comments, my approach is still applicable.

Comment: @ C.R.: No, I'd rather suggest to use one of the C++ string functions to split the string (maybe in a loop ...). Since youre in C++ here. C strtok() is cumbersome and it sort of breaks the paradigm using it from C+ + where you have "nice" strings.

Comment: im actually going to apply your concept to my program and see how it goes. My computer science class however has not covered vectors and is highly focused on dissecting the very nature of code in general ( for instance breaking a cstring apart and evaluating every character for different purposes). The class isnt so much major real life problem solving but more of understanding how every last detail of an array works and the nature of parsing files. With that its a little hard to implement programs to do things such as this because were not encouraged so much to use c++ functions

Comment: `while( !file.eof())` Who taught you to do this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit my computer science professor at University of TN

Comment: @ColinRickels: He should turn in his credentials, because he taught you _very_ wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit bold statement, it hasn't failed me yet and certainly isn't the bug behind my program so i find the point your attempting to make irrelevant to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is certainly vague. However, here's one way of doing that:

```
std::ifstream ifile("filename_and_path"); //Requires <fstream>

//check to see if the file is open or not:
if (!ifile.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "Something went wrong!" << std::endl;
    exit(1);//stop program execution. Requires <cstdlib>
}

std::string temp;
std::string state;
std::vector <std::string> tokens; //Requires <vector>

//std::getline requires: <string>
while(std::getline(ifile, temp)) {
    std::istringstream iss(temp);//initialize the stream to the contents of the line

    //keep parsing over the stream into tokens separated by ' ' (space) characters
    while(std::getline(iss, temp, ' ')) {
        //store all the tokens:
        tokens.push_back(temp);
    }

    //UPDATED to read ALL states. (I misread the question.)
    //we know that the last two parameters are always numbers, so use this
    //to our advantage:

    //if an even number, then we have two words, get and concatenate them:
    if (tokens.size() % 2 == 0) {
        state = tokens[0] + " " + tokens[1];
    }
    else {
        //this is an odd number of parameters. This means that this is a state
        //with one word (e.g.: Maryland)
        state = tokens[0];
    }

    //this is the end of one line, might as well print out the state name:
    std::cout << state << std::endl;
    state.clear();//empty the string for the next iteration
    tokens.clear();//empty the tokens for the next iteration
}
```

Comment: If the state consists of only one word, the code doesn't work. You have to test whether the second parameter is a number, or, split the strings into tokes separated by space, put them in a vector<string>, and remove the last 2 elements from the vector (the ones that are numbers), then display the remaining vector.

Comment: To the mysterious downvoter, could you please enlighten me as to what way you think my post could be improved, please?

Comment: I didn't down-voted you though :)) So I would use your code, but just `push_back` the tokens into a vector.

Comment: @vsoftco: I appreciate your honesty. Thank you. Also, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::vector to store all std::string tokens in each line then use iterator to read the value. This solution shall work for general state names with any length not just one with two-word like New Mexico as long as the last two tokens of each line in the file represents double and int value.

```
int readin(const ifstream& file)
{
  ...

  string val;  
  vector<string> v;

  while (val = file.get() )
  {
     v.push_back(val);     
  }

  //assign concatentaion from element 1st to nth-2
  for(vector<string>::iterator it = v.begin(), it != v.end()-2;it++)
     account[count].stateName += *it + " ";  

  //assign element nth -2
  account[count].miles = atof(*(v.end()-2).c_str());
  //assign element nth -1
  account[count].rests = atoi(*(v.end()-1).c_str());

 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok everyone i asked my teacher for the answer and she said all i had to do was use getline()  ;,D   cracking me up i was about to apply 20 lines of code to solve a one line C function.